# How to Handle Blank Request Header with Rest API calls in WCF

Tags: json, rest, api, wcf, faultcontract

One of my client is getting error message "The message with To 'http://XXXXXX/api/XXX/XXXX.svc/REST/Anonymous/XXXX/XXXX' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree." and scenario was when client send a request where Request header body was empty with post call then we got this message. Now we need to handle this exception and need to change error message. Please find below for example

[Click here for sample request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7A3wD.jpg)

Comment: `when client send a request where Request header body was empty` - The request header body? What's that?

Comment: Actually In request body suppose to send User id and password to authenticate. In case if they not send both values (User id & password) then it will be a empty header body. Now we need to handle this exception.